# How to get start time and end time of a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads started from main method.

How to calculate the start and end time of the thread?

your help would be highly appreaciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just get the current time at the start and at the end of the `run()` method.

```
private long startDate;
private long endDate;

@Override
public void run() {
    startDate = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        // Your code here
    }
    finally {
        endDate = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

From comments: Use `System.nanoTime()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` depending on your precision needs.

Comment: Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` might be more efficient, and if you want to measure a short interval try `System.nanoTime()` instead.

Comment: i used GregorianCalendar object to perform this,as date is deprecated.  later used endDate.getTimeInMillis()-startDate.getTimeInMillis() to calculate the total time taken.

Comment: Agree with @PeterLawrey; update this to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `nanoTime()` and I'll upvote.